# Get all possible substrings and their count

Tags: ruby, substring

I'm trying to get all possible substrings and their count in a hash.
E.g.

```
 "abc" => { a: 1, b: 1, ab: 1, bc: 1}
```

For that I wrote the following code:

```
 def get_all(b)
     (0..(b.size-1)).to_a.combination(2).inject({}) { |h, g|
        s = b[g[0],g[1]]
        h[s] ? ( h[s] += 1) : ( h[s] = 1 )
        h 
      } 
 end
```

But somehow It does not work correctly, because for `"abchh"` It returns:

```
{"a"=>1, "ab"=>1, "abc"=>1, "abch"=>1, "bc"=>1, "bch"=>1, "bchh"=>1, "chh"=>2, "hh"=>1}
```

`chh` is in there **twice**, but I can't understand why. What do I wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Your code may be *used* a rails app, but it's got nothing to do with rails. It's pure ruby. I would suggest removing those tags.

Comment: Also, minor point: You said "**all** possible substrings", but have excluded the whole string itself. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 2):

[`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) can be called in various ways, including:

> ```
> str[start, length] → new_str or nil
> str[range]         → new_str or nil
> ```

The former expects *start* and *length*, whereas the latter expects a range denoting *start* and *end*.

So instead of two arguments `g[0]` and `g[1]`:

```
b[g[0], g[1]]
```

you have to pass a single argument `g[0]..g[1]`:

```
b[g[0]..g[1]]
```

Besides, you have to use `repeated_combination` in order to get the single characters as well:

```
(0..2).to_a.combination(2).to_a
#=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2]]

(0..2).to_a.repeated_combination(2).to_a
#=> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]]
```

Furthermore, your code can be simplified:

- use `a...b` instead of `a..(b-1)`
- prefer `each_with_object` over `inject` so you don't have to return the hash from the block
- set a default hash value via `Hash.new(0)`
- decompose the tuple array via `(i, j)` to have `i..j` instead of `g[0]..g[1]`

Example: (the `indices` variable can be inlined)

```
def get_all(str)
  indices = (0...str.size).to_a.repeated_combination(2)
  indices.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(i, j), h|
    h[str[i..j]] += 1
  end
end
```

Or, using two nested loops:

```
def get_all(str)
  (0...str.size).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |i, h|
    (i...str.size).each do |j|
      h[str[i..j]] += 1
    end
  end
end
```

Maybe the method is already doing too much. I'd probably split it into two methods: one for enumerating the substrings and another one for counting them.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning `Hash.new { 0 }` as an easy improvement.

Comment: @Stefan how would you include the single characters as well? `a`, `b` etc

Comment: Your "simplified" code fixes the bugs, but exposes a new one: This approach does not include single-letter substrings. Because, for example, `[0,1,2].combination(2)` does not include `[0,0]`, `[1,1]` or `[2,2]`.

Comment: @TomLord thanks, I've overlooked that. I've updated my answer.